# Do you know of any recommended ActionScript 3 style guides?

Tags: actionscript-3, coding-style

Are there any recommended ActionScript 3 style guides publicly available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe has this: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions

It's fairly complete, and fairly well done.

Comment: Link is now broken, but I assume the following is similar to what you were referencing: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Coding%20Conventions/

Answer (score 2):

There is this guide by the [`Actionscript Flash Guru`](http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/6-flash-gurus-style-guide-a-best-practices-for-actionscript-3-as3), which misses a few things, but Adobe's [guide](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions) simply covers it all. For additional information and syntax-specific convention, I would strongly suggest you check out Adobe's book, `Programming with Flash CS3`, found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as3_programming.pdf), or in the Help section of your Flash program.

Comment: Adobe's Guide seems to have moved. [Try this.](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Coding%20Conventions/)